# Pagination Sort in Cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp 3.x i can't do paginate order in a find

This is my controller:

```
//AgentsController.php
public function show()
{
    $agents = $this->Agents->find()
    $this->set('agents', $this->paginate($agents));
}
```

And here part of my view

```
//show.ctp
<!-- ....... -->
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('full_name', 'Nome', array('escape' => false)); ?>
        </th>
        <th>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('username', 'Email', array('escape' => false)); ?>
        </th>
        <th>
            <?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('regions', 'Regioni', array('escape' => false)); ?>
        </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
<!-- ....... -->
```

Where i wrong?

Comment: You mean when clicking on one of the sort links? If that is the case, what is the generated url?

Comment: /admin/agents/show?sort=username&direction=asc

Comment: Can you show the generated SQL that is shown in debukit?

Comment: There isn't order by. Only Select, From, Join, Limit and offset

Comment: Is username a column of the agents table?

Comment: In this example case isn't it, but in my project is an associated table (Users.username)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Paginator will block any attempt of sorting by a column that does not exist in the primary table of the query you are using. In this case you have 2 options. The first option is changing the sort links to tell cake that the column belongs to a related table:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Users.full_name', 'Nome'); ?>
```

Or you can tell it in the component that sorting by a given set of columns is allowed:

```
$this->paginate = ['sortWhitelist' => ['full_name', 'username']]
```

Comment: Good! it works. I haven't sortWhitelist in my controller. Thanks!

Comment: @Pratik The answer probably shouldn't say "or", according to the docs you _must_ use the `sortWhitelist` option in case you want to sort on associated data, and the field must be supplied in `Users.full_name` format. See **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering**

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893881/cakephp-3-x-sorting-of-another-model-is-not-working

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$this->paginate = ['sortWhitelist' => ['full_name','username','regions'],'limit' => 3];
```

This will also set pagination limit too.

Comment: This is almost the same as the 6-month-old accepted answer, changing the limit (which isn't in the question). Not a useful answer.