# Cakephp 3.x Sorting of another model is not working

Tags: sorting, cakephp-3.0, paginator

I have two models Users & Roles

Here "Roles hasMany Users" and "Users belongsTo Roles"

When the user saved we're also asking user's role & record saved.

**Problem :** 
I have list of users with column firstname, lastname,roles. Each & Every column has sorting but on roles sorting is not working.

Role Table contains "name" field for Role name.
I have referred below link but it doesn't working for me.
[Pagination Sort in Cakephp 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948164/pagination-sort-in-cakephp-3-x/28961659#28961659)

**UsersController:**

```
public function index() {
     $this->paginate = [
                'contain' => ['Roles'],
                'conditions' => [
                    'Users.user_type <>' => 1
                ]
            ];

            $this->set('users', $this->paginate($this->Users));
            $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
}
```

**index.ctp**

```
 <tr>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('firstname',__('First Name')) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('lastname',__('Last Name')) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('email',__('Email Address')) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Roles.name',__('Role Associated')) ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('status',__('status')) ?></th>
                <th class="actions"><?php echo __('action') ?></th>
            </tr>
```

Let me know any solution you have.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 18):

You just have to use this:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'sortWhitelist'=>['Roles.name']
];
```

Comment: To be a bit more precise: you also have to include all other columns you want to sort.
In Controller-Action
`code
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Roles'],
    'sortWhitelist'=>['Roles.name', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'status']
];
`
[link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#control-which-fields-used-for-ordering)

Answer (score 1):

**UsersController.php**

```
 $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Roles'],
            'conditions' => [
                'Users.user_type <>' => 1
            ],
            'order' => ['Users.role_id' => 'ASC']
        ];
```

Use 'order' => ['Models.field' => 'ASC/DESC']

Comment: Thanks for answer but I want Sorting. Sorting on "Role Associated" field by clicking.

Comment: Try use the 'sort' key on you contain: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#sorting-contained-associations

Answer (score -1):

(I would add a comment to you question but I don't have enough reputation points.)

I am having the same issue.

This is happening because of the way containable behavior works.  When CakePHP gets all the roles for an associated user, it issues a separate query (instead of using a join on the main query).  Then it puts it all together in a nice object to use.  Take a look at the sql in debug kit.

When you ask it to sort by role name, it can't because the table Roles is nowhere to be found in the main query.  I am guessing you getting an error like this:

`Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: Roles.name`

To make this work, you're going to have to figure out how to join the Roles table to the Users table in the main query for this to work.  This is also why it works the other way.  If the Users table belonged to the Roles table you wouldn't have this issue because the Roles table would be joined in the main query.

Another way to make it work could be to use the Roles model for the main query.  But if your user's table has other hasMany associations that you want to sort by, this isn't going to work. (Which is my case.)

I've just started getting into CakePHP 3, so I really don't have an concrete answer at this point, but I hope this points you in the right direction.